# Google Compute VPN multiple remote networks

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have two networks listed in the "Remote network IP ranges" and the VPN is flapping between them. Only one of the remote networks is ever reachable at a time. How can I get it to keep both networks available all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Google Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn) doesn't support multiple SAs, you need to establish one SA with a traffic Selector that has all the subnets which most of the routers should have it, If your hardware doesn't support it then you need to create one tunnel for every subnet.